# How to make a widget transparent for selected mouse events

Tags: c++, qt, mouseevent, eventfilter

I'm working with a QDial object that is intended to be controlled with a mouse wheel, it works fine as such, emitting `valueChanged()` signals when necessary.

I would like to put a semi-transparent QToolButton on top of it, allowing users to click on the button (and set QDial value to a pre-defined number) while maintaining the ability to use the mouse wheel to control QDial as usual.

I experimented a bit with the `TransparentForMouseEvents` attribute:

```cpp
ui->toolButton_Example->setAttribute(Qt::WA_TransparentForMouseEvents);
```

The problem is, the above code switches off all events, including the ability to emit the `clicked()` signal.

Is there a way to make a QToolButton transparent selectively for `MouseWheelEvents` while preserving the ability to respond to `MouseClick` events? Or would this require rewriting the event filter from scratch?

Just to clarify, this question is about making QToolButton being transparent to `MouseWheel` events while still allowing it to respond to `MouseClick` events. It is not about making the button transparent in the graphical sense.

Comment: Please add the answer in the answer box, not into the question. Otherwise, I will be adding it as a community wiki, See: [How to treat an old question which had an answer edited into it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/289344/how-to-treat-an-old-question-which-had-an-answer-edited-into-it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`QObject::installEventFilter`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#installEventFilter) to have the parent object filter the events before they reach the tool button. Then, override the parent's [`QObject::eventFilter`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#eventFilter) to handle/ignore the event.

I create an example below:

mainwindow.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QToolButton>

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MainWindow();

    bool eventFilter(QObject *watched, QEvent *event) override;

private:
    QToolButton tool_button_ignored_;
    QToolButton tool_button_handled_;
};
#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

mainwindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"

#include <QDebug>
#include <QEvent>
#include <QHBoxLayout>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
{
    tool_button_ignored_.setObjectName("tool_button_ignored_");
    tool_button_ignored_.setText("Ignored button");
    tool_button_ignored_.installEventFilter(this);

    tool_button_handled_.setObjectName("tool_button_handled_");
    tool_button_handled_.setText("Handled button");
    tool_button_handled_.installEventFilter(this);

    QWidget *central_widget = new QWidget{this};
    QHBoxLayout *layout = new QHBoxLayout{central_widget};
    layout->addWidget(&tool_button_ignored_);
    layout->addWidget(&tool_button_handled_);
    this->setCentralWidget(central_widget);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
}

bool MainWindow::eventFilter(QObject *watched, QEvent *event)
{
    if (watched != &tool_button_ignored_ || event->type() != QEvent::Wheel)
    {
        qDebug() << event->type() << watched->objectName() << "handled";
        return QMainWindow::eventFilter(watched, event);
    }
    else
    {
        qDebug() << event->type() << watched->objectName() << "ignored";
        return true; // stop being handled further
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

<sup>Answer [provided](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/68317535/3) by [Bart M](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2874010/bart-m).</sup>

---

Subclass QDial and override `MousePressEvent` and `MouseReleaseEvent`:

```cpp
#include <QDial>
#include <QMouseEvent>

class QSuperDial : public QDial {

public:
    QSuperDial (QWidget *parent = nullptr) : QDial(parent) {}
    virtual void mousePressEvent (QMouseEvent *event) override {
        emit sliderPressed();
    }
    virtual void mouseMoveEvent (QMouseEvent * event) override {}
    virtual void mouseReleaseEvent (QMouseEvent *event) override {}
};
```

Promoting QDial to QSuperDial results in a QDial object that 'behaves' like a button when pressed, emitting `sliderPressed` signal, while still being responsive to `MouseWheelEvent` (like a normal QDial).